# Angular custom validation directive - errors does not behave as expected

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I try to write a custom validator in Angular 7.0.5, but I'm unable to get and display errors.

Tried to debug the code and searched both google and stackoverflow for answers or hints.

Below the template I use:

```html
<form #formWithDirective="ngForm" name="formWithDirective">
  <input ngModel #desiredWithDirective="ngModel" inFuture="2018-04-27"
    type = "date"
    name = "desiredWithDirective">
  <div *ngIf="desiredWithDirective.errors?.future">
    {{ desiredWithDirective.errors | json }}
  </div>
</form>
```

The directive:

```js
import { Directive, forwardRef, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Validator, AbstractControl, ValidationErrors, NG_VALIDATORS } from '@angular/forms';
import { MyValidators } from './my-validators';

@Directive({
  selector: '[ngModel][inFuture],[formControl][inFuture],[formControlName][inFuture]',
  providers: [{
    provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => FutureDirective),
    multi: true
  }]
})
export class FutureDirective implements Validator {
  @Input()
  inFuture: string;

  constructor() { }

  validate(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
    let date: Date;
    if (this.inFuture !== '') {
      date = new Date(this.inFuture);
    }

    return MyValidators.isFuture( date )( control );
  }

  registerOnValidatorChange?(fn: () => void): void;
}
```

And the actual implementation of the inFuture function:

```js
import { ValidatorFn, AbstractControl, ValidationErrors } from '@angular/forms';

export class MyValidators {
  static readonly isFuture: (condition?: Date) => ValidatorFn
    = (condition?: Date): ValidatorFn => (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
      if (control.value === null || control.value === '') {
        return null;
      }

      const selectedDate = new Date(control.value);
      const currentDate = (condition == null) ? new Date() : condition;
      const isFuture = selectedDate > currentDate;

      return isFuture
        ? null
        : { 'future': { currentDate, selectedDate } };
    }
}
```

I expect that an error is displayed if I select a date in the past. But no error is shown. If I debug the code and execute `MyValidators.isFuture( date )( control );` in chrome console I get the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: MyValidators is not defined
    at eval (eval at push../src/app/my-validators/future.directive.ts.FutureDirective.validate (future.directive.ts:25), <anonymous>:1:1)
    at FutureDirective.push../src/app/my-validators/future.directive.ts.FutureDirective.validate (future.directive.ts:25)
    at forms.js:792
    at forms.js:608
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at _executeValidators (forms.js:608)
    at forms.js:573
    at forms.js:608
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at _executeValidators (forms.js:608)
```

Any hint on how to tackle this problem would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you add `MyValidators` in app.module.ts?

Comment: It has its own module: ```MyValidatorsModule``` witch declares and export the directive. As the debugger is able to break inside the validator function I assume that part works ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I didn't change anything in this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7v73kd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts) and it works fine but still gives the same console error when you call the function. As you didn't share your ngModule: didn't you just forget to declare your directive?

Comment: Thank you for your message. I have declared and exported the directive. It has its own module (```MyValidatorsModule```) - ```@NgModule({
  declarations: [FutureDirective],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports: [FutureDirective]
})
export class MyValidatorsModule { }```

Comment: Sorry - stupid me; we have 2019 ... and I've tried with the wrong date ... very embarrassing. Thank you very much for your time and effort to help me!